# IntelliJ Hot Deploy Resources from dependency modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources, multi-module, hotswap

I have searched the web for almost 8 hours and tried all solutions but none of them seemed to work.

The problem I have is that all resource files coming from a dependency module are not being hot deployed in Jetbrain's IntellJ IDEA. We have resources such as xhtml, css etc. in all of them. Only the resources from the module producing the WAR are being hot deployed.

I already tried to manipulate the exploded artifact in the project settings dialog, deleted the module maven-dependencies from the artifact (they are included as jar files, that's probably why the contents of the module jars don't get hot deployed) but it just won't work at all.

Is it just not good practice to have multi modules that provide resources?

Has anyone figured out how to configure the artifact correctly to get both Java and resources to Hot deploy / Hot Swap?

As I mentioned, all the changes I do in Java classes living in the subprojects are reflected immediately.